# Why timestamp in MySQL JDBC have to be corrected with 'GMT-6:00'?

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I have a table contains a regular `datetime` typed column, and when selecting `mysql` command line returns the correct result:

[image]

but when it comes to JDBC, it'll return `2020-02-03 08:00:00`. I have to use `TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-6:00")` to regulate it.

On my server, the time zone related options are:

[image]

But seems the result JDBC driver returns is neither in my current time zone, nor the UTC. Is this because of something wrong on my MySQL server...?

Currently I'm using `mysql:latest` on Docker Windows and `mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.19`, the `TZ` environment of Docker container has been set to my local time zone.

Many thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the column is of type `DATETIME`? You have tagged this with `sql-timestamp` and a `TIMESTAMP` column is an altogether different thing. The current session time zone should have no effect on retrieving a previously initialized `DATETIME` column, which is not the case with a `TIMESTAMP` column.

Comment: @Booboo I rechecked this in MySQL workbench and it's indeed `DATETIME`. I think I just mis-tagged the problem. sorry.

Comment: Are you retrieving the value as a `java.time.LocalDateTime`? If so, see https://bugs.mysql.com/93444

Comment: @GordThompson nope. I first discovered the problem when I retrieved the value as `LocalDateTime`, but then I just use plain JDBC stuff to retrive the value as `Timestamp`, the problem still exist... is this somewhat MySQL JDBC bug...?